# accessing related data directly (and skipping linking class) in many to many relation in ef core

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

Lets say I want to have a class `A` with many `B` with many `A`;
I'm able to achieve that by creating class `AB`, adding `ICollection<AB> ABs` field to `A` and `B` classes and then accessing `B` through `ABs` property of class `A`. And this works.
But i was wondering is there a way to access related `B` data directly from class `A`, rather than doing that through `ABs` property.

I would imagine few ways of doing this (neither one of which I managed to get to work):

- `public ICollection<B> Bs => this.ABs.Select(item => item.B).ToList();`, but it doesnt, I have null exception in that even though I do include `ABs` and `Bs` with this `context.As.Include(item => item.ABs).ThenInclude(item => item.B);`.
- ef core's fluent api (no idea how to do)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using Context;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using var context = new ZContext();
      context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
      context.Database.EnsureCreated();
      var A = context.As.Include(item => item.ABs).ThenInclude(item => item.B);
      foreach (var a in A) {
        Console.WriteLine(a.Bs);
      }

      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Context
{
  public class IDed
  {
    #region Constructors
    public IDed()
    {
      ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    } 
    #endregion

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
  }
  public class A : IDed
  {
    public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> Bs { 
      get {
        return ABs.Select(item => item.B).ToList();
      }
    }
  }
  public class B : IDed
  {
    public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
  }
  public class AB
  {
    #region Constructors
    public AB()
    {

    }
    public AB(A a, B b)
    {
      this.AID = a.ID;
      this.BID = b.ID;
    } 
    #endregion

    public A A { get; set; } public Guid AID { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; } public Guid BID { get; set; }
  }
  public class ZContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=111.db3");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
      #region Keys
      mb.Entity<AB>().HasKey(item => new { item.AID, item.BID });
      #endregion
      #region Relations
      // ???
      #endregion
      var a1 = new A();
      var a2 = new A();
      mb.Entity<A>().HasData(a1, a2);

      var b1 = new B(); 
      var b2 = new B();
      mb.Entity<B>().HasData(b1, b2);
      mb.Entity<AB>().HasData(
        new AB(a1, b1),
        new AB(a1, b2),
        new AB(a2, b1),
        new AB(a2, b2)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

With 1st method I get `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')'` error even though I `Include` and `ThenInclude` all the same fields.

I realize that `AB` class will have to stay in any way, but would this configuration be possible to achieve, and what would be correct way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is caused by EF's inference of default mapping conventions. That is, when building the entity model, EF comes across property `A.Bs` and tries to find a database mapping for it. It's at that very early moment that the exception occurs. Once you know that, the fix is easy: just unmap the property:

```
[NotMapped]
public ICollection<B> Bs
{
    get
    {
        return ABs.Select(item => item.B).ToList();
    }
}
```

Or

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
{
    ...
    mb.Entity<A>().Ignore(a => a.Bs);
```

Of course, even without the exception the property should be unmapped, because you don't want it to be reflected in a database association.